# Как вывести количество строк файлов постранично?

Tags: php

Привет всем подскажите как реализовать, есть скажем 100 тхт. файлов в них записаны строки разного количества , как вывести количество строк файлов постранично. Я уже делал вот так и дело втом что выводится на всех файлах лиш одна сума по последнему файлу [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
   $files = glob("../data/*.*");

$fnumber = '10';

foreach($files as $file){

$name[] = basename($file);

$size = round(filesize($file)/1024,2);

$count = count(file($file));

$summa += count(file($file));

}


$counts = count($files);

$pages = ceil($counts/$fnumber);

$page = $_GET['page'];  

if(!$page OR $page=='')  
{  
        $nav_min = 0;  
        $nav_max = $fnumber - 1;  
}else{  
        $nav_min = ($page * $fnumber) - $fnumber;  
        $nav_max = ($fnumber * $page) - 1;  
}  


# Вывод  
 for($i = $nav_min; $i <= $nav_max; $i++)

{ 
        echo $name[$i]; // выводится 

           echo $size;   //  НЕ выводится 

            echo $count;   //  НЕ выводится 

} 

            echo $summa;   //  выводится 



    # Навигация  

    for($fpr = '', $i =1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
    {
        echo $fpr=(($i == 1 || $i == $pages || abs($i-$page) < 2) ? ($i == $page ? "<b style='font-size: 14px'>[$i]</b> | " : ' <a href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> | ') : (($fpr == ' ... ' || $fpr == '')? '' : ' ... '));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логичный результат. Foreach, который перебирает и получает массив не связан с for, который выводит этот самый массив. Поэтому foreach отработал, и остались последние результаты $size и $count - они и оказываются в дальнейшем выводе. Нужен двумерный массив. Что-то типа (только вместо $name лучше $id использовать) :

```
foreach($files as $file){
    $name = basename($file);
    $files[$name][“name”] = basename($file);
    $files[$name][“size”] = round(filesize($file)/1024,2);    
    $files[$name][“count”] = count(file($file));    
    $summa += count(file($file));    
}
```

---

Должно быть как-то так:

```
$id = 0;
foreach($files as $file){
    $name = basename($file);
    $filesarray[$id][“name”] = basename($file);
    $filesarray[$id][“size”] = round(filesize($file)/1024,2);    
    $filesarray[$id][“count”] = count(file($file));    
    $summa += count(file($file)); 
    $id++;   
}

    echo $filesarray[$i]["name"]; // выводится
    echo $filesarray[$i]["size"];   //  НЕ выводится
    echo $filesarray[$i]["count"];   //  НЕ выводится
```

Comment: незнаю но так мне не выходит шото

Comment: А вы прям так код использовали? Это лишь пример двумерного массива был, а не решение. Выше добавила правки более или менее должно быть для вашего кода.